# Why Does My Microphone Stop Working When I Use A KVM Switch?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, webcam, kvm-switch

I recently bought a KVM switch to use the same keyboard and mouse between my work computer and my personal computer. My work computer is an iMac, and my personal computer is a home built Windows gaming computer.

Since starting to use this KVM switch, I've experienced 3 different microphone units fail on my personal Windows computer, but still work on other computers. I've used a Blue Snowball, and 2 different Logitech webcams (all USB hookup). The Snowball was NOT hooked to the KVM switch, the webcams both were, but all three present with the issue - no audio detection in any program or in windows audio manager. However, these devices all work fine on other machines.

My keyboard and mouse work with the switch. But on my desktop exclusively, 3 separate microphone devices has all shared the same problem.

I just completed basic DISM and SFC through the Windows 10 cmd prompt in Admin mode. SFC reported corrupted files but said it fixed them.

Any suggestion past this point?

Oh, and Windows Administrave Event Viewer reports error 0x80004005 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this fixed yet or not. I had this same problem and it took me a while on google to pin down the answer. My KVM switch has two types of USB ports: USB and USB 2. When I plugged my USB mic into the standard USB port, it would not work. But when I used the USB 2 port, then it started working just fine on both PC's.